# C++ Passing Object by Reference

Tags: c++, object, pass-by-reference

First a disclaimer. I've been reading the multitude of questions on this topic, yet I can't get mine to work for me. Mostly I was basing my attempt off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147038/passing-object-by-reference-in-c) link, which seems to imply that as long as the function definition has & in it, then I can just pass the object into the function by name. However I keep getting the following errors:

> assembler.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   assembler.cpp:56:21: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Symbol_Table&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Symbol_Table (*)()’
>     get_input(Table_obj);
>
> assembler.cpp:30:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void get_input(Symbol_Table&)’
>    void get_input(Symbol_Table& Table_ptr)

As for my actual code, the relevant bits are below. The get_input function is just reading from a file and creating an object of a different type to work with. Through the course of the program running, the Symbol_Table object will have it's members changed so I need to pass it by reference without it being const, which was the only "solution" I could find.

```
void get_input(Symbol_Table& Table_ptr)
{
    do_stuff();
}

int main()
{
    Symbol_Table Table_obj();
    get_input(Table_obj);
}
```

I don't think the class definition of Symbol_Table is needed, but I can edit it in if needed.

Comment: in the code you show the parameter is completely ignored and you just call a free function. Could it be that in you original code either `do_stuff()` or `get_input()` is a member function of `Symbol_Table` ? If not I neither understand the code nor the question.

Comment: What happens if you just `Symbol_Table Table_obj;`? Most vexing parse... `Table_obj` is a function pointer.

Comment: @101010: It's not the most vexing parse (though it is related).

Comment: Slightly vexing parse.

Comment: Added a comment to the answer below explaining the issue if I drop the brackets.

Comment: Irrelevant. Because you have some other problem doesn't change the fact that your declaration is currently wrong!

Answer (score 1):

```
Symbol_Table Table_obj();
```

That doesn't create a variable called `Table_obj` of type `Symbol_Table`, that's a declaration for a function called `Table_obj` which takes no arguments and returns a `Symbol_Table`.

Do one of these:

```
Symbol_Table Table_obj;
Symbol_Table Table_obj{}; //C++11
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a function named `Table_obj` which will return `Symbol_Table`. This is not what you intend.

```
int main()
{
    Symbol_Table Table_obj; // Construct an object
    get_input(Table_obj);
}
```

This is like:

```
int get(); // Function
```

But you want:

```
int get; // Variable
```

Confusion reason:

```
int get(0); // int constructor takes one argument
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
Symbol_Table Table_obj();
```

does not make a `Symbol_Table` object named `Table_obj` but instead makes a function named `Table_obj` that takes nothing and returns a `Symbol_Table`.  Change it to

```
Symbol_Table Table_obj;
```

and it will compile just fine.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but doing so gives me a huge error beginning with "myassembler: In function `_start': (.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'".

Comment: @DwayneH: That's some other unrelated problem. You now need to go fix that problem. Previously you were only masking it.

Comment: Oh joy. Thanks then. Back to google I go.

Comment: @DwayneH I agree with lRiO.  your code (with some dummy stuff) [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5c60eee72445516)(ignore the warning).  You must have another issue.

Comment: Yeah fair enough. I'll accept the duplicate prompt since that did actually solve the problem.