# Passing reference as object in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that C++ references are not objects, but seems that I can pass references as objects.

In the code below, `v1` and `v2` are references, and are assigned as `double &v1 = x1` through the constructor. Then, while calling from `foo()`, should I have `bar(double &)` or `bar(double)`? Based on `double &v1 = x1`, shouldn't there be `bar(double)`?

This looks confusing to me. Can someone explain it?

```
#include <iostream>

class FooBar
{
private:
    double &v1, &v2;
public:
    FooBar(double &, double &);
    void foo();
    void bar(double &);
};

FooBar::FooBar (double &x, double &y): v1(x), v2(y) {}

void FooBar::foo()
{
    bar(v1);
    bar(v2);
}

void FooBar::bar(double &x)
{
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    double x1 = {0.5}, x2 = {1.5};
    FooBar f(x1, x2);
    f.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at this old question, hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147038/passing-object-by-reference-in-c

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't clarify/answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

> Then while calling from foo(), should I have bar(double &) or
>   bar(double)? Based on double &v1 = x1, shouldn't there be bar(double)?

In this case it doesn't matter, `v1` is a reference and if you change it inside of bar, the variable that was used to initialized it will also change, regardless if the parameter of `bar` is declared as `double` or `double&`.

Have in mind that a reference is like a synonym to a variable. Even though the C++ standard does not specify how a compiler must implement references, every C++ compiler I know implements references as pointers. So basically, you are passing the memory address of the variable to the function anyway.